# Magento 2 best way to achieve a load time of less than 2.5 seconds

Tags: magento2, performance, pagespeed

Please elaborate the best methodologies and strategies to achieve a lesser **load time** in both **server side** and **Magneto side**. Tried out various strategies but couldn't achieve a load time of less than 4 seconds consistently. In some cases if I achieve 3.2 seconds or more it is not consistent. Please suggest the techniques you have employed to achieve lesser load time.

Has anyone integrated **Google Page Speed Module** either in Nginx or Apache? Does it improve the page load time?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - Heavy loading time (too many js files)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104583/magento-2-heavy-loading-time-too-many-js-files)

Comment: @MagenX  I want to know the best practices which others would have succeeded to improve the page load time. I want the best practices to be followed both in the Server side and Magento side whereas the thread you have provided is not solving my question.

Comment: you need to use search, then you have to work with your store, then you can see the problem and solve it, there are no such things as best practices ... every store is unique.